# Arrow operator placement C

Tags: c, struct, dereference

Using this example struct:

```
typedef struct
{
    uint8_t ary[2];
    uint32_t val;
}test_t;
```

These two code snippets are functionally equivalent:

Snip 1 (arrow operation inside sizeof bracket):

```
int main()
{
    printf("Hello World");
    printf("\n %d", sizeof(((test_t *)0)->ary));

    return 0;
}
```

Snip 2 (arrow operation outside sizeof brackets):

```
int main()
{
    printf("Hello World");
    printf("\n %d", sizeof((test_t *)0)->ary);

    return 0;
}
```

Both report the correct value if the size of ary is changed however I do not understand how the outside bracket example works as:

```
sizeof((test_t *)0) // Using memory address 0 as pointer to test_t. size of pointer should be 4 on 32 bit system
```

Therefore the outside arrow operation in snip 2 should be equivalent to:

```
4->ary or *4.ary
```

So why does snip 2 compile and run the same as snip 1

```
Expected output: 2
```

Comment: The extra parentheses are redundant and have no effect.

Comment: It's funny how `sizeof ((test_t *)0)->ary` works.

Comment: Yeah, `sizeof` is an operator, not a function.

Comment: @KamilCuk: yes, and how `sizeof (test_t *)0` does not :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quote from [N1570](http://chimera.roma1.infn.it/SP/COMMON/iso-iec-9899-1990.pdf) 6.5.3 Unary operators:

> ```
> Syntax
> 1   unary-expression:
>     postfix-expression
>         ++ unary-expression
>         -- unary-expression
>         unary-operator cast-expression
>         sizeof unary-expression
>         sizeof ( type-name )
>         _Alignof ( type-name )
> ```

As you see, the `sizeof` operator that takes expression doesn't require parenthesis.

Therefore both `sizeof(((test_t *)0)->ary)` and `sizeof((test_t *)0)->ary` are valid.

Note that `printf("\n %d", sizeof(((test_t *)0)->ary));` is invalid (invokes *undefined behavior*) because wrong format specifier is used. `%d` is for printing `int`. `sizeof` operator returns `size_t` and the format specifier for that is `%zu`.